# The servlet call order failed

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

Good afternoon!
In an example I did in class, when I debug the servlet comes in front of the filter.

On the system I'm doing the filter is called first that the servlet ... and this is causing problems.

I'm doing the login part of the system.

I am using version 3.0 of the servlet.

In class I did not need to use xml, but in some sites indicate to do this ... which also did not work.

**Index**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
            <div>
            <form action="template/inicio.html" method="post"> 
                <label for="login">Login </label>     
                <input type="text" name="login">

                <br>

                <label for="senha">Senha </label> 
                <input type="text" name="senha">

                <br>

                <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
            </form>   
        </div>
        ${msg}
</body>
</html>
```

**FiltroLogin**

```
package filtro;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
* Servlet Filter implementation class FiltroLogin
*/
@WebFilter(
        dispatcherTypes = {
                DispatcherType.REQUEST, 
                DispatcherType.FORWARD, 
                DispatcherType.INCLUDE, 
                DispatcherType.ERROR
        }
                    , 
        urlPatterns = { 
                "/FiltroLogin", 
                "/template/*"
        })
public class FiltroLogin implements Filter {

    /**
    * Default constructor. 
    */
    public FiltroLogin() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
    * @see Filter#destroy()
    */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
    * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
    */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();



        if(session.getAttribute("login") != null ){
            //Se estiver logado, deixa a pagina ser exibida
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }else{
            //mandar embora
            res.sendRedirect( req.getContextPath() );
        }
    }

    /**
    * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
    */
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

**ControleLogin**

```
package control;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.firebirdsql.jdbc.parser.JaybirdSqlParser.function_return;

import model.Funcionario;
import persistence.FuncionarioDao;
import persistence.LoginDao;

/**
* Servlet implementation class ControleLogin
*/
@WebServlet({"/ControleLogin","/template/inicio.html", "/template/logout.html"})
public class ControleLogin extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
    * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
    */
    public ControleLogin() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
    * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        execute(request, response);
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        execute(request, response);
    }

protected void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try{

                String url = request.getServletPath();

                if(url.equalsIgnoreCase("/template/inicio.html")){
                    String login = request.getParameter("login");
                    String senha = request.getParameter("senha");

                if(new LoginDao().logar(login, senha).booleanValue() == true){
                    Funcionario func = new LoginDao().buscarUsuario(login);

                    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

                    session.setAttribute("nomeP", func.getNome());

                    response.sendRedirect("template/indCadastro.jsp");
                }else{
                    request.setAttribute("msg", "<div class = 'alert alert-info'>"+ "Email ou senha Incorretos!"+"</div>");
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("../index.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }

                }else if(url.equalsIgnoreCase("/template/logout.html")){
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

                    session.removeAttribute("nomeP");

                    session.invalidate();

                    response.sendRedirect( request.getContextPath() + "/");
                }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear. What are you trying to achieve, what are you doing in your test, what do you expect to happen and what happens instead? Why is your servlet mapped to 3 different URLs? Why don't you use 3 different servlets instead?

Answer (score 0):

I solved The index, was with the "Action =" template / Logar "", when I switched to "Action =" Logar "", it worked.
Silly mistake.